# How to sort or rearrange the items in Gutenberg WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Is it possible to sort the Gutenberg Blocks by Alphabetical order ? Please check the screenshot for reference.

[image: Gutenberg Editor]

I would like to sort Alphabetical like Heading, Image, List, Paragraph …

**Answer:**

I found the solution. Actually the block-editor.js file missing the sorting functionality.

If anyone need to sort the items, please follow the below steps.

1. Open wp-includes/js/dist/block-editor.js
2. Find the method BlockTypesList()
3. Replace var items = _ref.items, with

   var items = _ref.items.sort(function (a, b) {
                       var a1 = a.title, b1 = b.title;
                       if (a1 == b1) return 0;
                       return a1 > b1 ? 1 : -1;
                   }),
4. You can compile the JS file to minify

**NOTE:** Its not advisable to touch the core WordPress file, so please be careful and if you need 100% mandatory to modify, please proceed, else wait for the core developer to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add custom code to the Gutenberg plugin?
If so, try to follow the following:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_list.asp